# Botão com glyphicon-remove com problema de tamanho

Tags: html5, bootstrap-3, button

Por favor veja esse link em demo: http://www.bootply.com/eiG8eKm3Ao

Estou tentando centralizar o "X" dentro do botão vermelho.

Código:

```
<button id="del_photo" type="button" style="width:20px;height:20px" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" title="Excluir">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style="color:white;font-size:1em"></span>
</button>
```

Alguma solução ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitua:

```
<button id="del_photo" type="button" style="width:20px;height:20px" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" title="Excluir">
```

Por:

```
<button id="del_photo" type="button" style="padding:15px" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" title="Excluir">
```

É uma das soluções...

Comment: Oi @MagicHat, aqui funcionou ! Valeu. Confere aqui: http://www.bootply.com/A0AUtnVpaS